# Will a crew or crews for one or more commercial launch vehicles to the ISS really be announced in August 2018?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, nasa, commercial

The Washington Post article [Boeing faces a significant setback with the spacecraft it is designing to fly NASA astronauts](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2018/07/21/boeing-faces-significant-setback-with-spacecraft-its-designing-fly-nasa-astronauts/) includes the following statemt:

> The leak is likely to delay its launch schedule and is another setback for a program that has faced a number of problems. The trouble also comes as Vice President Pence **is expected to announce the crews for the first missions** during a ceremony in early August at the Kennedy Space Center in Florida.

Is it certain that the vice president will announce the names of astronauts in each crew, and if so, is it certain what the mission, or even the launch vehicle and capsule will be? I'd thought there were two different, competing commercial crew projects. Will one crew be trained for multiple launch vehicles, or will there be different crews trained separately for each commercial effort?

Comment: I don't know about crews, but four Commercial Crew test pilots were nominated in 2015 https://spaceflightnow.com/2015/07/09/nasa-names-cadre-of-commercial-crew-astronauts/. All them are training for BOTH types of the ships - Dragon and CST-100.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the crews will be annonced Aug. 3.

https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-to-name-astronauts-assigned-to-first-boeing-spacex-flights

> NASA will announce on Friday, Aug. 3, the astronauts assigned to crew the first flight tests and missions of the Boeing CST-100 Starliner and SpaceX Crew Dragon, and begin a new era in American spaceflight. NASA Administrator Jim Bridenstine will preside over the event, which will begin at 11 a.m. EDT on NASA Television and the agency’s website.

Comment: Great, thanks! I noticed at the bottom that it looks like there will be one Reddit AMA for everyone.